# Gravity Forms not loading under https, jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, wordpress, ssl

I am using the Gravity Forms plugin on my WordPress site. I am serving the page over HTTPS and this is breaking the form.

It looks like the issue is how the site is trying to load jQuery. There are 23 JavaScript errors on the page, which seem to be due to a failed jQuery load `"Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"`.

If I go to the page where the source is trying to pull the jQuery file, you'll see the `error:https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js?ver=3.4.2`

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

And this screenshot is the reference in the page source:

[image]

So I have been told I'd want to look into that - that's where the ultimate issue is, but I don't really know what to do next.

Is it failing because of Gravity Forms, the HTTPS plugin from WordPress, or my SSL certificate?

Comment: The jQuery content delivery network doesn't support https. You'd need to load jQuery from the Google or Microsoft CDNs instead, which [do support https.](http://jquery.com/download/) How you do that depends on which script is requesting the file from `code.jquery.com`. Is it being requested by one of your theme files, or one of your plugins? (You could do a full text search of your wp-content folder for 'code.jquery.com' to find out.)

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing me in the right direction so quickly! I've just installed a Wordpress plugin that lets me choose the CDN.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-jquery-cdn/installation/
But still not working, and if I look at the source code, it's still requesting code.jquery instead of google, so I guess it must be the plugin, right?

Your help on this is much appreciated!

Comment: I finally changed the URL to Google's CDN in the functions.php file. Now it's requesting the correct CDN and working flawlessly. Thanks for your help mate!

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer showing how you can include jQuery over HTTPS. It's particularly important to use the `wp_enqueue_script` function so that you don't end up including jQuery twice or more if other files or plugins use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `code.jquery.com` domain doesn't support https. You need to load jQuery either from your own domain or from the Google or Microsoft CDNs instead.

To load jQuery from your own domain over https, simply do this:

`<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>`

To load it from Google's CDN over https, do this:

```
<?php 
function jquery_cdn() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js', false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery_cdn');
```

Omitting the 'https' in the above sample is deliberate; it ensures that jQuery will be loaded over the same protocol as your site, be it HTTP or HTTPS.